# Windows 7 Installer Constantly Running

Tags: windows-7

I'm running Windows 7 RC.  Recently I noticed that my CPU was being pegged by msiexec.exe.  Another symptom is that when I try to uninstall applications from the control panel I see this error:

"Another program is being installed. Please wait until that installation is complete, and then try installing this software again."

It's like the installer service is performing an installation in the background.  I've rebooted several times, but nothing has worked.

Is there a way to get the msiexec service to forget about whatever installation it's trying to perform?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: 
Disabled the Windows Installer service in the administrative services list.

Reboot.

Re-enable the service (set to manual start)

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301)

Comment: I tried with no luck.  Thanks for the suggestion.